# LeafletJS: prevent clicking on map when clicking on circlemarker

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a leaflet map and there is both an event attached to the map (click) and an event attached to the circlemarker (click). Now I want to change the color of the circlemarker, but the trouble is that the event of the map fires as well and this is interfering with the logic of the circlemarker click.

How do I prevent the map event from firing when clicking on the circlemarker?

```
var circleMarker = L.circleMarker([point.lat, point.lng], {
  radius: 8,
  fillColor: "#ff0097",
  color: "#000",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8
}).addTo(drawmap);

circleMarker.on("click", function(e) {
  e.originalEvent.preventDefault(); //This does not work
  circleMarker.setStyle({ fillColor: '#1b1b1b' });
});


drawmap.on('click', function(e) {
//something unrelated
}
```

Comment: Did you try to stop the event propagation inside the on click handler for the marker eg. `e.stopPropagation();` ?

Comment: @DavidDomain just tried, does not work sadly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not seeing a way to handle this internally within Leaflet's event object. Perhaps you can track with an external flag:

```
var isCircleEvent = false;
circleMarker.on("click", function (e) {
    circleMarker.setStyle({ fillColor: '#1b1b1b' });
    isCircleEvent = true;
});


drawmap.on('click', function (e) {
    if (isCircleEvent) {
        //reset the flag and return;
        isCircleEvent = false;
        return;
    }
    //something unrelated
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Late entry:

In the [Leaflet docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#marker) there is an option when creating a marker, `bubblingMouseEvents`, that allows for the prevention of event propagation. This works when creating a `circleMarker` too.

So in your case:

```
var circleMarker = L.circleMarker([point.lat, point.lng], {
  radius: 8,
  fillColor: "#ff0097",
  color: "#000",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8,
  bubblingMouseEvents: false
}).addTo(drawmap);
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is the answer OP was looking for.